# disable helm mode for find files

Tags: helm

IDO had this disable the special mode and fall back to vanilla `find-files`. It was useful to be able to use environment variables and their expansion in path names for example.

Is there something similar for `helm-find-files` (a key to hit during `helm-mode-find-file` which falls back to `find-files`?

Moreover, my `C-x C-f` is not bound to `helm-find-files`, yet I still get `helm-mode-find-file` when I hit `C-x C-f` (or when `M-x find-file` for that matter). Also puzzled by this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Disabling helm mode for find-file

### Adding an action

There doesn't appear to be a built-in way to switch from helm-filnd-files back to the default Emacs' `find-files`. However, you can add an `action` to do this:

```
(defun old-ff (&optional no-op) (interactive)
       (call-interactively 'find-file))
(helm-add-action-to-source "Fallback find-file"
                       'old-ff
                       helm-source-find-files)
```

### Binding a key to the action

With this code, you will get a new option in the "Action Menu" called "Fallback find-file". However, getting there is a bit awkward - you need to invoke the "Action Menu" first (TAB by default), then scroll to the entry. To add a keybinding to access this directly from the mini-buffer, use the following:

```
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-q")
  (lambda () (interactive)
    (helm-quit-and-execute-action 'old-ff))
```

I'm a little confused by this system, and the documentation is not clear. From my experiments you must use a named function in `helm-add-function-to-source` if you want to later call that function from `helm-quit-and-execute-action`. However, `helm-add-function-to-source` requires a function that takes one argument, and `helm-quit-and-execute` will only call the function without passing an argument. I've worked around this incompatibility by defining `old-ff` to take an optional argument that doesn't actually get used.

### Config

To get this code invoked at the appropriate time, I use `use-package` as follows:

```
(use-package helm
  :ensure helm
  :config
  (progn
    (defun old-ff (&optional no-op) (interactive)
           (call-interactively 'find-file))
    (helm-add-action-to-source "Fallback find-file"
                           'old-ff
                           helm-source-find-files)
    (define-key helm-map (kbd "C-q")
      (lambda () (interactive)
        (helm-quit-and-execute-action 'old-ff)))))
```

## Getting rid of helm mode for `C-x C-f`

Regarding your second question, you probably have set `(helm-mode 1)` in your init. This will over-ride the normal `C-x C-f` keybinding to provide the helm interface instead.

Answer (score 6):

There is a built-in way to disable `helm` taking over a `completing-read` handler:

```
(add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist '(find-file))
```

Execute this after enabling `helm-mode`.  Alternatively, wrap it with `eval-after-load`:

```
(eval-after-load 'helm-mode
  '(add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist '(find-file)))
```

As for the other question, there is nothing built-in to switch back to vanilla file finding.  The best you can do is deactivating automatic expansion by hitting `C-<Backspace>`.